# Getting NullPointerException at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.parse(RuntimeInstance.java:1198)

Tags: java, maven-3, velocity

Migrated from

```
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
```

to

```
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
```

Upon the execution of following instruction

```
VelocityContext vc = getVelocityContext(valuesMap);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
Velocity.evaluate(vc, writer, "[generate email processor - event id = " + event.getId() + "]", bodyTemplate);
```

I am getting

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.parse(RuntimeInstance.java:1198)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.parse(RuntimeInstance.java:1181)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.evaluate(RuntimeInstance.java:1297)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.evaluate(RuntimeInstance.java:1265)
        at org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity.evaluate(Velocity.java:180)
        at net.nationalpayment.core.backend.GenerateMessageProcessor$EventProcessor.generateMessage(GenerateMessageProcessor.java:1361)
        at net.nationalpayment.core.backend.GenerateMessageProcessor$EventProcessor.run(GenerateMessageProcessor.java:1155)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.parse(RuntimeInstance.java:1198)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.parse(RuntimeInstance.java:1181)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.evaluate(RuntimeInstance.java:1297)
        at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.evaluate(RuntimeInstance.java:1265)
        at org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity.evaluate(Velocity.java:180)
        at net.nationalpayment.core.backend.GenerateMessageProcessor$EventProcessor.generateMessage(GenerateMessageProcessor.java:1361)
        at net.nationalpayment.core.backend.GenerateMessageProcessor$EventProcessor.run(GenerateMessageProcessor.java:1155)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am initializing the RuntimeSingleton once during the execution of application as below.

```
if(!RuntimeSingleton.isInitialized()) {
        RuntimeSingleton.init();
    }
```

Why am i getting the NullPointerException ?

Comment: why don't you debug your code? that way, you can see the state of variables.

Comment: i tried and figured that  instruction( Parser parser = (Parser) parserPool.get();) is throwing it(probably parserPool = null ). I thought it is due to non-initialized org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance class. Initialized the same, as mentioned in the problem statement to initialize it. But still I am getting it.

Comment: I would guess your template is causing this null-pointer. - Which line of the template? Impossible for me to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In velocity (version 1.7). Properties have been externalize to a property file named velocity.property.

After specifying the below mentioned properties leaving all others with default values as per my requirement.The issue got resolved.

runtime.log = /tmp/velocity.log